# How to update data in a List<? extends Map<String,?>>

Tags: java, android, list, hashmap

I'm making use of a `List<? extends Map<String,?>>` that I populated with data.

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
while (cursor.getPosition() < cursor.getCount()) {
    item.put("ProdName",cursor.getString(2));
    item.put("ProdSize", cursor.getString(3));
    item.put("ProdPack",cursor.getString(4));
    item.put("OrdQty","0");

    //list.add(item);
    list.add(i, item);
    item = new HashMap<String,String>();    
    cursor.moveToNext();
    i = i + 1;
}
```

How do I update a value for example in the `OrdQty` field?

Comment: You mean like `list[3].put("OrdQty","7")`? You haven't told us how to modify an `item`, so I'm guessing.

Comment: it wont let me use the put command :(

Comment: It's because it's a list and not an array. It should be list.get(3).put("ordQty","7").  BUT don't do that...

Comment: I am stucked i the same situation..what is the type of `item` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Duffymo is right, you shouldn't use a map as a pseudo-object.

This is how to update an object at a specific place (`index`) in a list.

```
Map<String,?> ugly = list.get(index);
```

Then you can do whatever you want with the object ugly.

If you did it properly, it would look like this...

```
Product p = list.get(index);
p.setOrderQuantity(17);
```

Answer (score 6):

Looks like a *very* bad design to me.  Java's an object-oriented language.  Why don't you provide a real contract and create Product and Order objects?  Give Order a List of Products to maintain.  What you're proposing is less self-explanatory and harder to write and maintain.

Comment: im having to use this method to populate a listview while giving me the option to overide the getView method

Comment: I don't see how a better design using real objects conflicts with that goal.  Everything you wrote was about "view", which is separate from the object model.